# Storing values inside a map of struct vector

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, struct, iterator

I have a problem inserting values into a `map<int,vector<pair<structA,structB> > >`.
I have 2 `structA` and `structB` which i use to store data. Then using a couple of `for` loops, I store the values into the map.

Below is the simplified code:

```
vector<structB>::iterator b = vecB.begin();
vector<pair<structA,structB> > myVec;
map<int,vector<pair<structA,structB> > > myMap;
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    for (vector<structA>::iterator a = vecA.begin(); a != vecA.end() ; a++) {
        //...do stuff here
        //push data into myVec
    ++b
    }
    myMap.insert(make_pair(i,myVec));
}
```

I get results like this from `myMap`.
For simplicity's sake, lets say `structA` and `structB` are PC1-PC10 and User1-User20 respectively.
*int i = 1*
PC1:User1
.  .  .
PC10:User10

*int i = 2*
PC1:User1
.  .  .
PC10:User10
PC1:User11
.  .  .
PC10:User20

The results from `myMap` isn't what I wanted. It should be something like this:
*int i = 1*
PC1:User1
.  .  .
PC10:User10

*int i = 2*
**PC1:User11

.  .  .

PC10:User20**

It seems that for `myMap` *i=2*, it will contain the values from *i=1* as well.
I have tried `myVec.clear()` before inserting the vector into the map but I need the values from `structA` to remain untouched.
So any suggestions on how can I store **only** the values for *i=2*?

Comment: You're calling `push_back` on an `std::map`...

Comment: @zenith Ah sorry. I changed it to back to `insert`. Thanks for the reminder ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will accomplish what you probably want:

```
vector<structB>::iterator b = vecB.begin();
map<int,vector<pair<structA,structB> > > myMap;
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    vector<pair<structA,structB>> myVec; // Initialize empty vector
    for (vector<structA>::iterator a = vecA.begin(); a != vecA.end() ; a++) {
        //...do stuff here
        myVec.push_back(make_pair(*a,*b)); // Make a structA-structB pair and add it to myVec
        ++b;
    }
    myMap.insert(make_pair(i,myVec));
}
```

Comment: Its the same thing. What I want to achieve is that each `i` in the map contains the values for that iteration. Meaning to say in `i=1`, it contains only *PC1:User1* to *PC10:User10* and in `i=2`, it contains only *PC1:User11* to *PC10:User20*. And the values inside of PC1 remains the same for User11 to User20.

Comment: @JoelSeah If I understood correctly, you need to declare `myVec` in the outer `for`, before the inner `for`. Then for each `i` it will start with an empty `vector`, that you fill with PC1-10 and the corresponding Users. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, except that for example PC1 is a struct with `string paid` and `int num` and has the value PC1:1. I want to keep the values for PC1 for the next iteration `i`.

Comment: i meant `string pcid`

Comment: @JoelSeah Yeah I think what I described shouldn't change the contents of `vecA` so you just `push_back` your `structA`s from `vecA` to `myVec`, and it will always `push_back` the same values.

Comment: @JoelSeah Made an edit to my answer to demonstrate what I was saying

Comment: Thanks! One difference is that I didn't add the pointer to `a` and `b` as demonstrated in ur answer and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: @JoelSeah Ah okay, great!